# How to cut data to be uniform?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, data-science

I have such data shown on the histogram below:

[image]

I would like to cut using median, but the outcome I received was filtering on values, not their count (horizontal axis is value, vertical is quantity of such values). I want it to be something like rectangle on the plot. How can I make it? My present code is shown below:

```py
def cutting(arr):

    df = pd.DataFrame(xy)
    df = df[df<df.median()]
    
    return df.to_numpy()

arr = cutting(arr)

plt.hist(arr, bins=100);
plt.show()
```

Edit: generated example of the data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Kt11m7F15kUsStRSj3LIYCkszzon_X9/view?usp=sharing

Edit_2 (better explanation of what I'd like to have): When you look at the plot above, there are some spikes that tell us, there are much more of some values than the other. I don't want it. I want to keep it as it is BUT, when some of the data is bigger than median, of any other threshold value it is changed (lower) to the threshold. After such filtering, data shown on the plot would be smooth, without spikes.

Comment: We will need some sample data to help you out.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't give the data. It's simple 0-200 counter. I just want to cut these spikes you can see on image.

Comment: so you must be able to provide some code to simulate the data if it's so simple...

Comment: Okay, I've generated example data with similiar distribution.